# Request testnet ETH and LINK tokens for the Sepolia testnet

Tags: etherscan, testing, testnets, faucets, sepolia

I am trying to get a sepolia test link from faucets.chain.link, I have inserted my wallet address, I have selected the Request type (0.1Eth), I have verified that i am human; But the send request button remains inactive,  what I'm i not doing right?